# Overloading prefix and postfix increment in class timer. Problems while debugging

Tags: c++, class, timer, operator-overloading

I need to overload increment for class Timer. Members of my class are minutes and seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Timer
{
private:
  int minutes;           
  int seconds;            

public:

  Time(){
     minutes = 0;
     seconds = 0;

  }
  Time(int m, int s){
     minutes = m;
     seconds = s;

  }

  void displayTime()
  {
     cout << "M: " << hours << " S:" << minutes <<endl;
  }

  Time operator++ ()  
  {
     ++seconds;          
     if(seconds >= 60)  
     {
        ++minutes;
        seconds -= 60;
     }
     return Time(minutes, seconds);
  }

  Time operator++( int )         
  {

     Time T(minutes, seconds);

     ++seconds;                    
     if(seconds >= 60)
     {
        ++minutes;
        seconds -= 60;
     }

     return T; 
  }
  };
  int main()
  {
  Time T1(18, 23), T2(19,12);

  ++T1;                    
  T1.displayTime();       
  ++T1;                   
  T1.displayTime();      

  T2++;                  
  T2.displayTime();      
  T2++;                   
  T2.displayTime();       
  _getch()
  }
```

When I debug, it says

> Compiler: Default compiler
>       Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win"
>       Executing  make...
>       make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" all
>       g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"
>
> ```
> main.cpp:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Time' with no type
>
> main.cpp:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Time' with no type
> main.cpp:29: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Time' with no type
>
> main.cpp:29: error: expected `;' before "operator"
> main.cpp:40: error: expected `;' before "Time"
> main.cpp:40: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Time' with no type
> main.cpp:40: error: expected `;' before "operator"
>
> main.cpp:54: error: expected `;' before '}' token
> main.cpp: In member function `void Timer::displayTime()':
> main.cpp:26: error: `hours' undeclared (first use this function)
>
> main.cpp:26: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
> main.cpp: At global scope:
> main.cpp:56: error: new types may not be defined in a return type
> main.cpp:56: error: extraneous `int' ignored
> main.cpp:56: error: `main' must return `int'
> main.cpp: In function `int main(...)':
> main.cpp:57: error: `Time' undeclared (first use this function)
> main.cpp:57: error: expected `;' before "T1"
> main.cpp:59: error: `T1' undeclared (first use this function)
> main.cpp:64: error: `T2' undeclared (first use this function)
> main.cpp:69: error: expected `;' before '}' token
>
> make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
>
> Execution terminated
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object should be of type Timer not Time.
try to match class name and constructor name.

Hour member is not defined in displayTime method.

```
void displayTime()
  {
     cout << "M: " << minutes << " S:" << seconds <<endl;
  }
```

Please refer following code
http://ideone.com/m50w2r